# Setting the result from a function to a variable and appending - inconsistency

Tags: bash, variables, awk

I need to get a result from a function to variable and then I want to append the result as a new column to the same file. I was using following code (example for getting the minimal value from column $2):

```
min="$(cut -f2 myfile.tsv | sort -n | head -1)"
awk -v min=$min '{print $0 "\t" min}' myfile.tsv > myfile_min.tsv
```

Input data example:

```
Backbone_1000 375 T X     
Backbone_1000 424 T EQ    
Backbone_1000 428 G EQ    
Backbone_1000 440 G EQ    
Backbone_1000 462 G EQ    
Backbone_1000 477 C EQ    
Backbone_1000 483 T EQ    
Backbone_1000 492 C EQ    
Backbone_1000 493 C EQ    
Backbone_1000 503 G EQ
```

Expected output:

```
Backbone_1000 375 T X   375  
Backbone_1000 424 T EQ  375  
Backbone_1000 428 G EQ  375
Backbone_1000 440 G EQ  375  
Backbone_1000 462 G EQ  375  
Backbone_1000 477 C EQ  375  
Backbone_1000 483 T EQ  375  
Backbone_1000 492 C EQ  375  
Backbone_1000 493 C EQ  375  
Backbone_1000 503 G EQ  375
```

The problem I have is, that it sometime works and next time it does not. It's a part of longer program that I submit to a cluster. Currently I am getting following error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `A' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

I was searching what we have on a cluster and so far I managed to find:

```
2.6.18-411.el5 GNU/Linux
```

Can anyone explain where is the problem or suggest another solution?

Comment: Please, some example data and expected result.

Comment: Do you have "myfile.tsv" as a variable? is it between "double quotes"?

Comment: The code you are showing looks fine. However, somewhere in your real code there is some variable with the name of the file that gets out of hand.

Comment: @fedorqui: Yes, you are right. I had a stupid mistake in the code because I was rewriting it and modifying it (2 for loops  - nested -with the same variable). Anyway,  thanks a lot to James Brown and hek2mgl for their  useful comments - I can learn from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about dealing with it directly in awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==1 { min=$2 } NR==FNR { if($2<min)min=$2; next } $0=$0 "\t" min' file file
Backbone_1000 375 T X   375
Backbone_1000 424 T EQ  375
Backbone_1000 428 G EQ  375
...
```

It reads `file` twice, searching for the minimum `$2` on the first run and outputing on the second.

Comment: Thank you! It solved the problem and it's more simple.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the value of `min` is sometimes unexpected and because **you don't quote it** - which you should(!) ;) - it gets subject of word splitting in shell. Looks like the value of `$min` is something like

```
foo bar A ...
#  ^   ^ space
```

which let's the shell call the following

```
awk -v min=foo bar A '{print $0 "\t" min}' myfile.tsv > myfile_min.tsv
# min value ^
# program       ^
# input files      ^          ^                ^
```

Use this:

```
awk -v min="$min" '{print $0 "\t" min}' myfile.tsv > myfile_min.tsv
# quotes   ^    ^
```

Sure, this will not fix the problem with `$min` being unexpected itself but at least it will not lead to a syntax error in the `awk` command. What you now need to do is to fix the commandline that set's `$min`.